# Should I Record Video using DJI Osmo in Landscape or Portrait/Vertical Mode for iPhone Portrait Orientation

Tags: iphone, screen-orientation, landscape-portrait

Im developing an iOS app that will only support portrait orientation. I’m recording a video for the app that will play in a continuous loop on the login/signup screen similar to Munchery’s app.

I’m using a DJI Osmo and an iPhone 7+ with Filmic to record the videos and I’m going to edit using FCP X and then play them using AVPlayer.

My question is when I shoot the videos should I shoot in landscape mode and then in FCP X edit them for portrait or just shoot in portrait to begin with?

It might seem like an odd question but this is my first time using the Osmo and iPhone 7+ to shoot anything and most videos using this setup are shot in landscape mode. I don’t want to shoot a bunch of scenes the wrong way then have to reshoot everything to fit the iPhones portrait mode since that’s the only orientation my app will support. But I don’t want to unnecessarily shoot in portrait when landscape will suffice.

[DJI Osmo Portrait/Vertical Mode](https://youtu.be/7dCkUXDxSyg?t=53)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recorded my first videos in the DJI portrait/vertical mode position and every time I played them back on my phone they would look fine in iPhone's landscape orientation but in iPhone's portrait orientation the videos would play in the center with a black bar on the top and another black bar on the bottom of it.

I went to the DJI store in Manhattan and the very helpful rep said the problem was I needed to first lock my phone in portrait orientation before recording in the DJI's portrait/vertical mode position to prevent that problem from happening. He said since I didn't have it locked even the iPhone was in a portrait position it was still recording in landscape mode.

I then asked him about the video I recorded playing in a portrait orientation inside my app and he said the only way that would work correctly is to record the video in DJI's portrait/vertical mode position. I had to scrap everything I recorded and rerecord again -sigh.

Basically if your going to use the DJI and your iPhone to record a video that will play in your app and your app will only support portrait orientation then:

1. make sure you lock the phone in portrait orientation
2. position your DJI to record your vide in the portrait/vertical mode position